# Setup phpMyAdmin inside website subdirectory

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, symlink, nginx-location

I have an NGINX web server with two domains and it also runs phpMyAdmin.

phpMyAdmin is working fine and I access it through the below non-https url:

public-ip-address/phpMyAdmin

This is how the symbolic link was setup:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html
```

Is there a way I can point phpMyAdmin to a website's subdirectory?

For example, I would like to access the phpMyAdmin login page by accessing the following URL:

```
domain1.com/phpMyAdmin/
```

How can I achieve this? domain1.com has https enabled. So it would also secure my phpMyAdmin login.

The server block is the same as the default block for NGINX. I have created a new config file by copying it to domain.com in the `/etc/NGINX/sites-available` folder.

The only changes are in the `server` and `root` path tags. Rest everything is default.

```
server domain1.com www.domain1.com;

root /var/www/domain1.com/html/
```

I am using certbot for Let's Encrypt SSL certificates. My server block config is shared below:

```
# Server Block Config for domain1.com
server {
    root /var/www/domain1.com/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Contents of /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: Right way to do it depends on your nginx config. If you can, add to your question the `server` configuration block for `domain1.com` domain.

Comment: Thanks. I shall edit the question.

Comment: Can you show how is your default PHP handler looking? Usually it is `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I have updated my server block config in the main question. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the `location` block that should work for you (at least the similar config works for me):

```
    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin(?<pmauri>/.*)? {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        index index.php;
        try_files $pmauri $pmauri/ =404;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$pmauri;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
```

Place it **before** the default PHP handler `location` block, or the default PHP handler block will take precedence and this configuration won't work!

Comment: So this location block shall be accessible at ```domain1.com/phpmyadmin```? Do I need to edit the existing symbolic links?

Comment: @ShoumikDas Under `domain1.com/phpMyAdmin` as you wrote in your question (case sensitive). To make the check case insensitive replace `~` with `~*`. No symlinks required at all for this config to work.

Comment: I get this error with ```sudo nginx -t```: ```nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain1.com:26
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed```

Comment: @ShoumikDas Maybe it is already present in your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`? If it is and it's value is `index.php`, remove the corresponding line from this `location` block.

Comment: @ShoumikDas If it still won't work, add contents of this file to your question too.

Comment: I get a 404 Not Found Error. These are the contents: ```# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;```

Comment: @ShoumikDas Nothing of this scrap is needed except `fastcgi_index index.php;` and `include fastcgi.conf;` :) Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes. That helped. I edited the location block to use ```include fastcgi.conf;```. I did not change anything in fastcgi-php.conf and it worked perfectly. Thanks a ton for your help. My phpadmin is now accessible through SSL. I am relieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another symlink to the domain1.com root, while keeping everything else same,  like you did for the default domain.

sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/domain1.com/html

Am I missing something?
I came to this thread while looking for a solution to another problem ([Nginx alias breaks due to try_files $uri alias bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093486/nginx-alias-breaks-due-to-try-files-uri-alias-bug)) but since you are already using symlink to phpmyadmin for the site you access through IP, you can do the same for any domain.