# Nginx alias breaks due to try_files $uri alias bug

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a versioned Symfony API instance that I want to configure in the following manner:

- api.com/api/v1 **->** /srv/api-v1/public/index.php
- api.com/api/v2 **->** /srv/api-v2/public/index.php

I've tried to approach this using nginx location and aliases, as it's Symfony we use try_files ([as recommended](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)) to check for an actual file prior to defaulting to `index.php`.

## Problem

It seems there is a [known nginx bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) that breaks the `$uri` variable with an `alias` and `try_files`.

How can I get around this bug to achieve my desired outcome?

**nginx conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name api.com;
    root /srv/default/public/; # default root when no version
 
    location /api/v1 {
        alias /srv/api-v1/public/;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /api/v2 {
        alias /srv/api-v2/public/;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        internal;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

## Attempted fix

Going by [this hacky fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642689/1072492) I have created the following which does work but generates a huge config file, not ideal:

```
upstream v1 {
    server 127.0.0.1;
}
upstream v2 {
    server 127.0.0.1;
}
server {
    listen 443 http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name api.com;
 
    location /api/v1 {
        proxy_pass http://v1;
    }

    location /api/v2 {
        proxy_pass http://v2;
    }
}
server {
    server_name v1;
    root /srv/api-v1/public/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        internal;
    }
}
server {
    server_name v2;
    root /srv/api-v2/public/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `if` and `$request_filename` with `alias` to avoid using `try_files`. You also need to use nested locations for the PHP URIs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319049/nginx-subdirectory-root-with-php/47332159#47332159).

Comment: Beware of using if in location context. See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another workaround exists which can be used when an `alias` directive is used in conjunction with the `try_files` one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62362487/7121513) answer for an example). Can you try the following config?

```
server {
    listen 443 http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name api.com;
    root /srv/default/public/; # default root when no version
 
    location ~ ^/api/v1(?<v1route>/.*)? {
        alias /srv/api-v1/public;
        try_files $v1route /api/v1/index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ ^/api/v1/index\.php$ {
            internal;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/api-v1/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/api/v2(?<v2route>/.*)? {
        alias /srv/api-v2/public;
        try_files $v2route /api/v2/index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ ^/api/v2/index\.php$ {
            internal;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/api-v2/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        }
    }
}
```

**Temporary update (to be expanded with explanation)**

OP asks an additional question:

> There's one slight issue with the defaults Symfony expects. The following three server variables `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` equal `/api/v1/index.php` but default Symfony nginx generates `/index.php`, is there a way to tweak that in the above?

I don't think this is the reason of incorrect Symfony behavior. While this variables of course can be tweaked, the most probable reason is incorrect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value. With the configuration above it will be equal to `/api/v1/some/path` but most likely Symfony expects just `/some/path` instead. Here is the configuration you can try to overwrite that variable:

```
map $request_uri $api_ver {
    ~^/api/v([12])/?  $1;
}
map $request_uri $api_route {
    ~^/api/v[12](/[^?]*)?(?:$|\?)  $1;
}
server {
    listen 443 http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name api.com;
    root /srv/default/public; # default root when no version

    location ~ ^/api/v[12]/? {
        alias /srv/api-v$api_ver/public;
        try_files $api_route /api/v$api_ver/index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ ^/api/v[12]/index\.php$ {
            internal;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $api_route$is_args$args;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/api-v$api_ver/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this should fix your issues, but if you **really** want to tweak `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, you can add two additional lines to the nested location:

```
        location ~ ^/api/v[12]/index\.php$ {
            internal;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $api_route$is_args$args;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI /index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/api-v$api_ver/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        }
```

but I don't think it is required for correct Symfony behavior.

**Update 2**

To prevent `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable from being an empty string, you have the following options:

1. Redirect the request from `/api/v1` or `/api/v2` to `/api/v1/` or `/api/v2/` (seems the best as for me):

   ```
   map $request_uri $api_ver {
       ~^/api/v([12])/  $1;
   }
   map $request_uri $api_route {
       ~^/api/v[12](/[^?]*)(?:$|\?)  $1;
   }
   server {
       ...
       location ~ ^/api/v[12]$ {
           return 301 https://$host$uri/$is_args$args;
       }
       location ~ ^/api/v[12]/ {
           alias /srv/api-v$api_ver/public;
           try_files $api_route /api/v$api_ver/index.php$is_args$args;
           location ~ ^/api/v[12]/index\.php$ {
               internal;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
               fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $api_route$is_args$args;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/api-v$api_ver/public/index.php;
               fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Explicitly add the trailing slash to the exact `/api/v1` or `/api/v2` requests:

   ```
   map $request_uri $api_ver {
       ~^/api/v([12])/?  $1;
   }
   map $request_uri $api_route {
       ~^/api/v[12](?:/([^?]*))?(?:$|\?)  /$1;
   }
   server {
       ...
       location ~ ^/api/v[12]/? {
           alias /srv/api-v$api_ver/public;
           try_files $api_route /api/v$api_ver/index.php$is_args$args;
           location ~ ^/api/v[12]/index\.php$ {
               internal;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
               fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $api_route$is_args$args;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/api-v$api_ver/public/index.php;
               fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

If the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable value should be prepended with `/api` string, you can try `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /api$api_route$is_args$args;` instead of `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $api_route$is_args$args;`.

If you want to tweak `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variables, add the

```
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI /index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
```

lines to the nested location.

Comment: Tested and so far this seems to work as expected, a much simpler solution. Thank you!

Comment: Having tested this a bit more there's one slight issue with the defaults Symfony expects. The following three server variables `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']`, ``$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` equal `/api/v1/index.php` but default Symfony nginx generates `/index.php`, is there a way to tweak that in the above?

Comment: Yes, most of them [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables are defined to their default values via the `/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf` (Debian based) or `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` (RHEL based) file. You can redefine them (only **after** file `fastcgi.conf` inclusion, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968482/expose-multiple-api-uri-on-the-same-nginx-server-block/62971843#62971843) answer for more explanation). It seems strange to me that a PHP application behavior can be dependent on any other variables than `REQUEST_URI` and `DOCUMENT_URI`.

Comment: I'll write an update to the answer soon, didn't have time to that right now.

Comment: Did you have any chance to look at this? Is it just a small tweak?

Comment: Started to write a really **big** answer yesterday and loose it with a system crash :( What are you asking for is a small tweak, you need to add `fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI /index.php;` and `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;` lines to the both nested locations after the `include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;` line, but I'm afraid your problems are coming from an incorrect value of `REQUEST_URI` variable (you need to strip `/api/vN` substring from it) and that tweak won't help you. Tweaking `REQUEST_URI` is more tricky. Meanwhile you can try this one, I'll try to give the whole answer today.

Comment: have added a large bounty to this question if there's any chance you could give a rewrite example to finish this up, thank you

Comment: Check an update, please. I think it should fix your issues. Your bounty deserves an explanation of that configuration and on tweaking FastCGI request meta-variables in general and I'll try to write one really soon, but it will take a couple of time I didn't have right now, I'm really sorry, my current project deadline is tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks I have tried this. There seems one last issue in that `REQUEST_URI' => '',` is empty when we expect it to be `'REQUEST_URI' => '/api/v2',`, that's what is breaking the Symfony routing.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI ` It doesn't seem to be applying the `/api/v1` prefix with the above.

Comment: The goal of the configuration I suggest is to strip `/api/v1` or `/api/v2` prefix from the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable. I don't know your Symfony app architecture or what `REQUEST_URI` value it actually expects for the `/api/v<number>/some/path` request, it may be `/api/v<number>/some/path` or `/api/some/path` or even just a `/some/path`. The first value can be avhieved with the first answer I suggested, but I think you need either second or third one.

Comment: The one required is `/api/v<number>/some/path` but none of the above produce that. Even using `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $api_route$is_args$args;` this value is still `''`

Comment: I think your suggestion is a mistake, that is exactly what the first answer does. To tweak the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variables use the recipe given at the end of the answer. Meanwhile try the second answer update.

Answer (score 0):

In the "hacky fix" you are missing the trailing `/` to your `proxy_pass` directives.
Here is a repo to easily test your implementation: https://github.com/MelwinKfr/nginx-workaround97

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759345/nginx-trailing-slash-in-proxy-pass-url) if you want more info about the trailing slash.

Comment: The attempted fix was broken because I had double uri `$uri $uri/`, changing to `$uri` fix that but it's still a huge amount of config.

Comment: You're right, with the try_files directives it works without the trailing slash. Even with double `$uri $uri/` as long as you finish the line with `index.php`. Hence I don't get what your problem is.
 
> but it's still a huge amount of config.
Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with the 'hacky fix' you can make it a little cleaner. Just put the repeated config into some other file. Then you can use `include` directive to import the other file.

*/etc/nginx/some_other_file:*

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm-php7.2.socket;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        internal;
    }
```

```
upstream v1 {
    server 127.0.0.1;
}
upstream v2 {
    server 127.0.0.1;
}
server {
    listen 443 http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name api.com;
 
    location /api/v1 {
        proxy_pass http://v1;
    }

    location /api/v2 {
        proxy_pass http://v2;
    }
}
server {
    server_name v1;
    root /srv/api-v1/public/;
    include some_other_file;
}
server {
    server_name v2;
    root /srv/api-v2/public/;
    include some_other_file;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the hack fix didn't originally work but thanks for the tidy suggestion